# Setting color using IStylingEngine in MAC

Tags: java, macos, swt, rcp, e4

In my SWT application in MAC, I was trying to set some colour in the text box when the validation is wrong using `org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.IStylingEngine`

```
method(IStylingEngine cssengine){
    cssengine.setClassname(txtEnterNumberHere, "ErrorBackGroundColor");
}
```

Which I am getting correctly working in  windows but not getting effected in mac osx

Any idea how to fix in mac?

Comment: Just doing a quick test here and this works for me on Mac OS X 10.9.4 with Eclipse 4.4 and Java 1.8.

Comment: Maybe if you showed us some more code with examples of how you are using this we could spot the problem.